# Which nosql database will provide best result

Tags: database

We are developing system for analytics. Whenever any user performs anything on our site, we log this into our database, but the data is so huge (abt 30 lakh rows everyday) that rdms will not give us the best results.Based on this data we are querying our database to generate some reports.Hence we are looking for a NoSql database.

On one hand, we have to optimize our write operation and on the other hand, we have to improve read queries also. one thing is that we don't have any update query.

Can anyone suggest which NoSql database will provide us the best result based on our requirement??

Comment: Lakh as in 100,000? I'm not sure if many other people know that. You may want to change it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the concepts of NoSQL, I recommend reading [Amazon's Dynamo design](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html). The document by the link is quite big, but it is worth reading.

One of the most popular are:

- [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Project Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)

The rest can be found [here](http://nosql-database.org/). Your input is really not enough to tell what will suite your needs best.